# React js Material UI Icons package installation

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, material-ui

The Material UI Icons package is not getting installed with the command(s):

```
npm install @material-ui/icons 
npm install @material-ui/icons --force 
npm i @mui/icons-material @mui/material
```

And throwing errors. I am not able to fix this.

This kind of error I get while installation:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: netflix@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/react@11.8.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/react
npm ERR!     peerOptional @emotion/react@"^11.5.0" from @mui/material@5.5.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!       @mui/material@"^5.5.3" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (@mui/icons-material)
npm ERR!     peer @emotion/react@"^11.0.0-rc.0" from @emotion/styled@11.8.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/@emotion/styled
npm ERR!       peerOptional @emotion/styled@"^11.3.0" from @mui/material@5.5.3
npm ERR!       node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!         @mui/
```

Answer (score 0):

To install Material UI Icons, use:-

```bash
npm i @mui/icons-material
```

Comment: It is also giving error: " ERESOLVE could not resolve".